# Difference between Enameled Aluminum Wire and Enameled Copper Wire

Tags: 1-wire

What's the different between enameled aluminum wire and enameled wire?
How to choose a professional enameled wire manufacturer?
Advantages of enameled copper wire?
Advantages of enameled aluminum wire?

Comment: different chemical properties ?

Comment: Aluminum exposed to oxygen is very quickly reactive and makes "transparent aluminum" (aka sapphire, corundum, a passivation layer, etc.) as fast as your heart beats. Bad news for soldering.

Comment: Alum. Wire is useful when desired to reduce mass, reduce cost in power transformers at the expense of 60% more cross-sectional area to match resistance, increase heat velocity, increase voice coil velocity in tweeters

Comment: Appears to be the manufacturer promoting enamelled wire

Comment: Why don't you tell use what your customers are using enamelled aluminium wire for? You're the manufacturer of it, not us!

Comment: Wow this stuff sounds way more useful than the stuff other manfrs make thats just used by elderly hippies to string beads on: `"Aluminium Enameled Wire and Copper Enameled wire are meant to carry electrical currents"`

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Copper is more conductive, requiring smaller cross-section for a given current (though more expensive) and easier to solder or otherwise connect.

Aluminum  is less conductive, requiring larger cross-section for a given current. Despite this, it is cheaper than copper. As @analogsystemsrf noted, aluminum very quickly oxidizes, preventing soldering. Also, depending on the specific alloy, aluminum will tend to deform under pressure, loosening from under improperly tightened screws, producing high-resistance connections. Special considerations are required for good connections, especially for high-current applications.

Comment: It is however lighter for the same conductance, which I think sees it used for voice coils.

Answer (score 0):

Aluminum wire cannot be soldered. Unless you achieve a gas-tight connection, oxygen will enter and degrade the surface by oxidizing, and resistance will increase.